# react-dnd set state or props within hover function

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I'm trying to update props within the hover function in my DropTarget but it seems this isn't possible? The action to redraw happens in componentDidUpdate, and I basically want to set some props/state within the value i read inside hover (if pointer is too far to the right, then set a prop which will trigger componentDidUpdate to execute - and hover is the only place i can listen for those changes afaik).
Is this possible, or is there otherwise another recommended approach?

Comment: similar to this: https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/705